# The right shebang for Vim to parse the file from the argument?

Tags: command-line, external-command, linux

I'm following the page where there is an example how to set-up [Vim as a system interpreter for vimscript](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_as_a_system_interpreter_for_vimscript) by setting the following shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/vim -nNesc:let&verbose=1|let&viminfo=""|source%|echo""|qall!
```

so I did the test by adding `%print`, but it prints the current script file.

I obviously don't want to parse my current file which consist commands for Vim, but I want to parse the file from the argument.

What shebang line should I use, so I can use the script as a parser for the file which I will specify in the argument?

For example to execute commands from `parser.vim` on file `my_file.txt` I would run:

```
./parser.vim my_file.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source%` should give you a hint what's going on: the first argument *is* the current script, while `my_file.txt` is the second argument.  Adding `args` or `ls` to the script confirms that.  This means you have to add `bnext` to the top of your script to edit the text file rather than the script itself.  It also means you'll have to manage arguments in your script.  The wiki page is misleadingly optimistic about that.

**Edit:** One way to overcome the problem of the current buffer pointing to the script itself is to add `bnext` to the shebang line.  However, running `bnext` before `source %` is too early (after `bnext` the script can no longer be sourced), and running it after `source %` is too late (the script has already run).  A workaround is to add it to a `SourcePre` autocommand.  But since an autocommand would consume the rest of the command line, it has to be wrapped in an `exec`.  And you probably also want to limit `SourcePre` to the script itself.  This leads to something like this, which mostly works:

```
#! /usr/bin/vim -nNesc:let&verbose=1|let&viminfo=""|exec "autocmd SourcePre ".fnameescape(expand("%:p",1))." bnext"|source%|qall!
```

You'd still need to do something about `args` if your script uses `argdo` and friends.